# How to set extent property in view after map initialize using openlayer3?

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers, openlayers-3

My purpose is pan the map upto a certain limit when we drag it (exactly like google map) after that it should lock. This support is present in Openlayer version 2.0 using Bounds. But in version 3 I have to set extent property while initializing view. I am stuck in this stage. View is not set after initialize the map.

```
  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([73.8, 18.5]),
      zoom: 12
    })
  });
```

Now I want to set 'extent' property in view

```
  map.setView(new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([73.8, 18.5]),
    extent: map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize()),
    zoom : 12
  }));
```

This code is not working. Is there any other way to do that or am I doing something wrong?
There is no error in console. But map is not display.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nh9fs74k/

Answer (score 7):

Instead of `map.setView(new ol.View({...........`

Use this piece of code after map init

```
.....
var myExtent = [xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax];
map.getView().fit(myExtent , map.getSize());
........
```

**UPDATE**
To prevent from dragging map outside the current extent do the following:

```
map.setView(
new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([73.8, 18.5]),
    extent: map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize()),   
    zoom: 12
  })
);
```

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/LLL7Lxrx/)

Comment: Thanks for response Pavlos. Yaa that is fine. Actually I am getting these values (xmin, ymin, xmaz, ymax) from "map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize())", Your piece of code is absolutely right, but my purpose is not solved, that map area should lock after certain area. if I hard code that values directly on 'extent' properties view initializer of map, it works. But that not feasible.

Comment: What are you trying to do???? What do you mean lock? Prevent from moving outside the extent. Please explain in detail or better make a fiddle to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Yes. Prevent from moving outside the extent.

Comment: there is a solution update for fit to extent is, transform your extent to 3857 srs as openlayers use. 
Thanks